# Strange error with PHP exec command?

Tags: php, exec, json

I just used exec command in PHP and I got this strange error.
1. I try to used php command like this :
test1.php content :

```
if (!function_exists('json_decode')) {

$file = 'log.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "Fail to load JSON");
exit;

}else{

$file = 'log2.txt';
file_put_contents($file, "Success to load JSON");
exit;

}
```

In command line : >>php test1.php

I got Success to load JSON decode.
But when i tried to run it like this:
Test2.php content :

```
$test = exec( 'nohup nice php '.'test1.php');
```

I ran `http://localhost/test2.php`

Then I got Fail to load JSON decode .

That mean seem I can't get json_decode work within exec command ? What's happen and how to use json_decode within exec command ?

Comment: Is it possible the path to your log file is incorrect when you call it from another file? Also, why dont you just create a regular function and call that instead of calling exec.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same host? Is it possible, that you run `php test1.php` on one machine, but script with `exec` on another? If so, then `json_decode` is only available since PHP 5.2.0. Check your PHP version by running this:

```
php -i | grep 'PHP Version'
```